How to refined the newcommand `wordbox` to better highlight the text with tcolorbox?
I just want to achieve the highlight function as it perform as the markdown highlight with the shadow and emphisize the words. I consult the docs of tcolorbox and I coded the following command configuration:
\newtcbox{\wordbox}[1][black]{
    on line,
    arc = 0pt,
    outer arc = 0pt,
    colback = #1!10!white,
    colframe = #1!50!black,
    boxsep = 0pt,
    left = 1pt, right = 1pt, top = 2pt, bottom = 2pt,
    boxrule = 0pt, bottomrule = 0pt, toprule = 0pt,
}

Buy using it, I get the following result:

Then I found three drawbacks of it:

The height of the box within text with different height perform differently.
he case didn't perform well with long text, it can't automatically wrap the next lines.
The performance at the last line of one page and it can't wrap to the next page.

Here below is the mwe of the document above, and it shows the question
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtcbox{\wordbox}[1][black]{
    on line,
    arc = 0pt,
    outer arc = 0pt,
    colback = #1!10!white,
    colframe = #1!50!black,
    boxsep = 0pt,
    left = 1pt, right = 1pt, top = 2pt, bottom = 2pt,
    boxrule = 0pt, bottomrule = 0pt, toprule = 0pt,
}
\begin{document}
The result of the command \char92 wordbox is to highlight the text like that:

I can \wordbox{eat} glass, it does not \wordbox[green]{hurt} me.I can \wordbox[blue]{eat glass}, it does not \wordbox[red]{hurt me}.\wordbox{I} can eat glass, it does not \wordbox[orange]{hurt} me.I can \wordbox{eat} glass, it does not \wordbox[green]{hurt} me.

But it has some drawbacks:
\begin{itemize}
    \item {The height of the box within text with different height perform differently. \par Example:\wordbox{aeiou} and \wordbox{ggpyyy} and \wordbox{bbbbdddd} (the height is not aligned)}
    \item {The case didn't perform well with long text, it can't wrap the next lines. \par
          Example: \wordbox{I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.}}
    \item The performance at the last line of one page and it can't wrap to the next page.
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2-3]

I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.\wordbox{I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.}I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.

I am sorry for the fact that cound't illustrate the behavior of the command \char92 wordbox at the end of the page, I just wonder how should I change the set of the tcolorbox option to achieve the desired result.Thanks! 

\end{document}

And here below is the PDF-result:

I just wonder how to align the text-box height with different fontsizes(as the standard of the longest letter like 'f'), and how to make the box can wrap automatically at the end of line and at the end of the page. Thanks a lot!

Is there any particular reason you don't want to use one of the packages which is designed to do this?

Just because I never heard of the soul package...

But it has such an obvious name :-). Who wouldn't associate highlighting text with a metaphysical position on the human condition?

Aha! the name of it is actually vivid! maybe that is because English is not my native language, and I don't know how to paraphrase the highlight properly. Thanks u very much  o(￣▽￣)ブ!

Well, it wasn't at all obvious to me either and I still find it an odd name. I think it is actually a combination of abbreviations something-other-under-lining, but I don't know what the so stands for. Is that a cat? How did you type it? >^.^<

Sorry for late reply, the 'o(￣▽￣)ブ' is someone put up his hand to show happiness and thankness to u. It's  called ’Emoticons‘(the text version of emoji).....  aha, it is provided for the “microsoft typing” on windows system, you can use Win+";" to raise the emoji panel, and you can see the ;-) sub-panel, and you can type w(ﾟДﾟ)w...(*￣０￣)ノ¯(°_o)/¯Σ(っ °Д °;)っ(Φ皿Φ) easily if you use Windows System.

Ah, thanks. my knowledge of windows is minimal. I'm familiar with emoticons - just hadn't seen this one. It makes me think of an owl, but with a cat's tail :-). (on some forums, typing the emoticon produces the corresponding emoji, too.)

This is not a direct answer to your question, but rather a don't-try-to-reinvent-the-wheel, at least when the wheel is of the extremely-complex-and-difficult-to-make-wheel variety.
Instead, use one of the existing methods to do the job. The best option may be engine dependent, but soul should work well even if you switch engines:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{soul}
\definecolor{hlcolour}{rgb}{.75,.75,.75}
\sethlcolor{hlcolour}
\NewDocumentCommand \wordbox { o m }
{%
  \begingroup
    \IfValueT{#1}{\colorlet{hlcolour}{#1}}%
    \hl{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{.75,1,.75}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.75,.75,1}
\definecolor{myred}{rgb}{1,.75,.75}
\begin{document}
The result of the command \char92 wordbox is to highlight the text like that:

I can \wordbox{eat} glass, it does not \wordbox[mygreen]{hurt} me.I can \wordbox[myblue]{eat glass}, it does not \wordbox[myred]{hurt me}.\wordbox{I} can eat glass, it does not \wordbox[orange]{hurt} me.I can \wordbox{eat} glass, it does not \wordbox[mygreen]{hurt} me.

But it has some drawbacks:
\begin{itemize}
    \item {The height of the box within text with different height perform differently. \par Example:\wordbox{aeiou} and \wordbox{ggpyyy} and \wordbox{bbbbdddd} (the height is not aligned)}
    \item {The case didn't perform well with long text, it can't wrap the next lines. \par
      Example: \wordbox[gray!10]{I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.}}
    \item The performance at the last line of one page and it can't wrap to the next page.
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2-3]

I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.\wordbox{I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.}I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.I can eat glass, it does not hurt me.

I am sorry for the fact that cound't illustrate the behavior of the command \char92 wordbox at the end of the page, I just wonder how should I change the set of the tcolorbox option to achieve the desired result.Thanks! 

\end{document}

[Tested with pdfTeX, luaTeX and XeTeX.]
